# Rails assets precompile failes with Too many connections

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

When I try to call `rake assets:precompile` in production, I get a "Too many connections" error.

I'm using Rails 3.2.3 and my database.yml is set to `pool: 5`

Any idea on how to fix this ?

Thanks

Comment: Try bundle exec rake assets:precompile, it may work.

Comment: Thats what I am doing: RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile.

Comment: Very strange... I stopped everything, unicorn, resque, faye and retried. It worked... I started everything and retried and it still works... I don't get it :(

Comment: Which database ru using? Sqlite or mysql? In case mysql that problem may be solved by restarting the mysql.

Comment: MySQL, but like I said, restarting the app made it work, then I guess it's not a mysql issue.

Comment: It's mysql issue only, I think its not configured properly. Refer the link whic I suggested in answer.